# On homeomorphic compact connected topological groups

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

I wish to thank Professor Claudio Gorodski for his very helpful
answers to my question on the webcite:
[If compact connected Lie groups are homeomorphic as topological space, are they isomorphic as Lie groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67030/if-compact-connected-lie-groups-are-homeomorphic-as-topological-space-are-they-i)

He said: Let $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ be two compact, connected Lie
groups with isomorphic homotopy groups in each dimension. Then their
Lie algebras are isomorphic.

Now my question is: If $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are two compact,
connected topological groups which are homeomorphic as topological
space, are there any isomorphism theorems?

Comment: Haven't we had this one before? I think the $p$-adic integers (for different $p$) was the example given -- all of these spaces are homeomorphic IIRC but for different $p$ they're not at all isomorphic as topological groups. I'm going from memory here so apologies if I'm off base.

Comment: .. or even as abstract groups.

Comment: What is IIRC?

Is your example a connected topological space?

Comment: sife -- good point, the groups of $p$-adic numbers are definitely not connected.

Comment: .. but in that case what's the problem with the examples in the thread you mention?

Comment: Kevin Buzzard said:

"I think the p-adic integers (for different p) was the example given -- all of these spaces are homeomorphic IIRC but for different p they're not at all isomorphic as topological groups."


What is IIRC?

Comment: sife -- iirc means "if I remember correctly". iirc, that is..

Comment: @Kevin - This question?  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44060/does-homeomorphic-and-isomorphic-always-imply-homeomorphically-isomorphic

Comment: Yes, apologies for the confusion. My example isn't connected so it's no good. 

Comment: @Steven -- yes! The link you give seems to answer the question.

Comment: Silly example: any group can be equipped with the indiscrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace *homeomorphic* with *homotopy equivalent* the answer is no. There are infinitely-many non-isomorphic topological groups which are homotopy equivalent (just as spaces) to $S^3$. Actually, these topological groups cannot be connected by a zig-zag of group homomorphisms which are homotopy equivalences. But of course all of them have the same homotopy groups.

Rector, David L.
Loop structures on the homotopy type of S3. Symposium on Algebraic Topology (Battelle Seattle Res. Center, Seattle, Wash., 1971), pp. 99–105. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 249, Springer, Berlin, 1971.

Comment: Fernando Muro--Are the examples mentioned above compact, connected topological groups? If they are compact, connected topological space, then they must be homeomorphic to $S^{3}$ by Poincaré conjecture .
Therefore we need not replace homeomorphic with homotopy equivalent.

Comment: They're not compact, but even if they were, Poincaré's conjecture would not apply since it is for *manifolds*.